# How do I produce the relationship diagram in Microsoft Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, database-diagrams

How do I produce the relationship diagram in Microsoft Sql Server?
Here is a visual of what I am talking about here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRhdN.png]

Answer (score 3):

it is called EER can be foundin SSMS 18

under

> Visual database tools Design Database Diagrams.

you find it in the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/design-database-diagrams-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15

so you can install a 17 er version of ssms

https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SSMS/README.md#sql-server-management-studio-download-links-and-release-info

And then

- Go to Sql Server Management Studio >
- Object Explorer >
- Databases >
- Choose and expand your Database.
  -Under your database right click on "Database Diagrams" and select "New Database Diagram".
- It will a open a new window. Choose tables to include in ER-Diagram (to select multiple tables press "ctrl" or "shift" button and select tables).
- Click add.
  -Wait for it to complete. Done!

or use some other tool like

https://dbeaver.io/download/

here is a the [manual for eer](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/ER-Diagrams/)